# How can I pass IdentityUsers with their IdentityRoles to the View?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, roles

I want to display Users with their IdentityRoles in the View how can i achive this?

**UserController.cs**

```
namespace WebApplication.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public UserController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public  IActionResult Index()
        {
            var users =  _userManager.Users;
            return View(users);
        }    
    }
}
```

**AplicationUser.cs**

```
namespace WebApplication.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
       
    }
}
```

**Tables in my Database**

[image]

**Result I wanna Acheive**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get the roles:

```
List<string> roles = _userManager.GetRoles(userId).ToList(); // for example:  { "Admin", "HelpDesk"} 
string roleDisplay = string.join(", ", roles); // "Admin, HelpDesk"
```

You could then store the roles on the model:

```
namespace WebApplication.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
       string Roles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Finally in the view:

```
<td>@Model.Roles</td>
```